# Why does CSS styling disappear in React when directly changing route in browser URI?

Tags: css, reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

I have a simple front-end React app created using npx create-react-app. The app is using react-router-dom routes. When I directly change the URI in the browser from say, `localhost:3000/` to `localhost:3000/search` it will navigate to the `<Route>`but with no CSS rendered; just HTML from the component.

How can I make sure CSS is rendered in the new route when directly navigating in the browser? My future goal is to be able to copy and paste a route in a new tab and navigate to the correct page and display results from an API.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I realized that react apps created using `npx create-react-app` allow you to import a css module for components.

Given the component, `Button.jsx`, you can simply create a css module with the convention, `[module-name].module.css`. For the case of `Button.jsx`, create a file named `Button.module.css`, import "styles" from the module. Styles will be an object containing all the CSS styles.

I if I had a folder named "components" with all my components, I could make a folder within "components", say called "compStyles", and create all the `[module-name].module.css` files in there.

Button.module.css:

```
/* class names must be camelCased */
.myButton {
     margin: 0 auto;
}

span {
    fontSize: 20px;
}
```

If I had the above mentioned file structure, I could import and use like so:

```
import React from 'react';
import styles from './styles/Button.module.css';

const Button = () => {
    return (
        <div className={styles.myButton}>
            <button><span>Some Button</span></button>
        </div>
    )
}
export default Button;
```

Styles for the span will be automatically applied, and any other class will be referenced by styles.className. Create one file for every component, and each component's CSS will take care of itself and not break like it would if it was in the public folder.

Answer (score 0):

Css style sheets will need to be imported either at the root level or within the file itself.

style sheets need to be imported when used and then the corresponding classname will need to be used within the component or tag.

Another useful way to set react css without style sheets is by using in line styles

e.g

```
<div style ={{float: "right", textAlign : "center"}}> </div>
```

EDIT

A really easy way to get styles going within a react project is install bootstrap.

then buttons and stuff can be assigned classNames such as

```
<div className = "jumbotron"></>
```

this will leave a grey box around the items.

```
<div className = "btn btn-primary"></>
```

this will give you a blue styled button.

Any more information or help within your application let me know and provide some code snippets.

Comment: Helpful to know that the root must be loaded. However the method of only using inline and bootstrap styles for all CSS would significantly effect performance, would make code unreadable, and would make it very difficult to achieve styles. I think a redirection to root and then further redirects would be more effective.

Comment: In that case include the import within the root file and then this should be applicable to your whole application. For large scale projects inline and bootstrap  would effect performance but for small scale applications it would not be an issue.

Answer (score 0):

You can use styled-components. styled-components are widely used in ReactJs and React Native and it's a perfect choice.

styled-component : https://www.npmjs.com/package/styled-components